# Мигание изображений при обновлении в Chromium 61

Tags: javascript, изображения, chromium

Страница подключается по WebSocket к серверу и запрашивает с него постоянно меняющийся кадр транслирующей веб камеры:

```
<script>
    function Initialize(){
        var Screen = document.createElement('img');
        Screen.onload = function(){URL.revokeObjectURL(Screen.src);};
        document.body.appendChild(Screen);
        var Rate = 50;
        var Preload = new Image();
        var Request = 'GetFrame';
        var MainSocket = new WebSocket(<?php echo $host;?>);
        MainSocket.onopen = function(){MainSocket.send(Request);};
        MainSocket.onmessage = function(event){
            if (Preload.src.length > 0){Screen.src = Preload.src;}
            Preload.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.data);
            setTimeout(function(){MainSocket.send(Request);},Rate);
        };
    }
</script>
...
<body onload="Initialize();"></body>
```

В обычном Chrome, в Firefox, IE изображения меняются плавно, как видео, даже без `Preload` - просто `Screen.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.data);`. А в Chromium версии 61, на котором настаивают заказчики, кадры мигают при загрузке!

**Можно как-то побороть это мигание в Chromium?**

Comment: Подождать. В бетах часто бывают баги, особенно дерганья. И еще тут как вариант - в фон ставить картинку после того, как загрузится.

Comment: @Iceman а зачем запрашивать как в ajax? почему сервер сам не отправляет кадры? ведь ws может это прекрасно делать.

Comment: @Вадим, да, я знаю, пробовал непрерывный поток. Но браузер не успевает чистить свою память от изображений, переполняется, грузит систему и ложится в итоге ))). Но даже при аналогичном с ajax подходе FPS получается выше на WS протоколе